# Apply Stripe Coupon only for selected payments of subscription

Tags: stripe-payments, subscriptions, stripe-connect

I need to apply stripe coupon for 3 months plan and 1 month plan.For the person subscribe to 3 moths plan will recieve 100% discount for the first payment and the person who subscribe for 1 month plan will recievie 100% discount for 3 concecative payments(for 3 months).

How this can be achieved within the stripe.We can use percentage or amount as the discount.

In addition to that, if the person upgrate the plan within the copoun applied period, is there a special way to distribute coupon amount using stripe

Answer (score 0):

You can add discount coupons to subscriptions by creating discount element and then append that id(response object) to subscription.
Ref: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts

if any help lmk

Comment: I am using the subscription discount. Thanks, But main issue is how to achieve 100% discount only for 3 payments of subscription. Eg 100%  fress for 3 months

Comment: You can achieve this by creating coupon object and pass coupon id to subscription object.
For example: stripe.coupons.create({
  percent_off: 100,
  duration: 'repeating',
  duration_in_months: 3,
  id: '25OFF'
}, function(err, coupon) {
  // asynchronously called
});

For Ref : https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_coupon

Comment: Yes, I nave done it ,but in order to test this with my webhook I think I need to wait 3 months. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually it depends what you want to do after this. Can you tell me ?

Comment: I need to test what I we have implemented above ,taking a similer senario but not need to wait 3 months.